# What is the proof behind $\lim f(g(x)) = f(\lim g(x))$?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, epsilon-delta

In general I see that we can evaluate $\lim f(g(x)) = f(\lim g(x))$ if $f$ is continuous. How do we know this? How do we prove this?

I tried looking at it with the epsilon-delta definition of a limit but I didn't get very far since I don't know how you even begin to analyze $f(\lim g(x))$.

Comment: Hint: This is true if $\lim g(x)$ exists. (If it doesn't, it is still possible the left side exists.)

Comment: So the conditions are, if $\lim g(x)=L$ exists, and $f$ is continuous at $L,$ then ...

Comment: Do you mean something like g(x) = 1/x not existing when x=0, but then if f(x) = 1/x then f(g(x)) = 1/(1/x) = x now exists?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that $f$ is continuous at a point $b$, and that $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=b$, then indeed$$f\left(\lim_{x\to a}g(x)\right)=\lim_{x\to a}f\bigl(g(x)\bigr).\tag1$$In fact, given $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that$$|x-b|<\delta\implies\bigl|f(x)-f(b)\bigr|<\varepsilon.$$And there is a $\delta'>0$ such that$$|x-a|<\delta'\implies\bigl|g(x)-b\bigr|<\delta.$$Putting all this together, we get that$$|x-a|<\delta'\implies\bigl|f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)-f(b)\bigr|<\varepsilon.$$Therefore, $(1)$ holds.

Comment: Did you mean $|x-a|< \delta$ in the second expression? Since $x \to a$ in both limits? or no?

Comment: @user537069 No. I wrote what I meant to write.

Comment: Does $g(a)$ need to be able to be evaluated? Why not write as $b$? How are you "putting it together"? I don't see why $|g(x) - g(a)| < \delta$ lets you combine it with $|x-b| < \delta$

Comment: @user537069 $g(a)$ doesn't even have to exist. How did I put it together? If $|x-a<\delta'$, then $\bigl|g(x)-g(a)\bigr|<\delta$. And since $\bigl|g(x)-g(a)\bigr|<\delta$, $\bigl|f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)-f\bigl(g(a)\bigr)\bigr|<\varepsilon.$

Comment: So you are basically subbing in $g(x)$ in for where $x$ is where it says $|x-b| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(b)| < \epsilon$?

Comment: @user537069 If subbing means substituting, then yes.

Comment: How can $g(a)$ not exist when we're using it in the condition $|g(x) - g(a)| < \delta$?

Comment: @user537069 My mistake. I wrote (twice) $g(a)$ where I should have written $b$. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I understand much better now!

Comment: @user537069 I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Does $f$ being continuous at $b$ allow you to relax the limit definition so that $x$ no longer needs to belong a deleted neighborhood of $b$? I.e instead of requiring $0\lt\lvert x-b\rvert\lt\delta\implies\lvert f(x)-f(b)\rvert\lt\epsilon$, you can just say $\lvert x-b\rvert\lt\delta\implies\lvert f(x)-f(b)\rvert\lt\epsilon$? Because $\lvert g(x)-b\rvert\lt\delta$ would not satisfy former definition since $(b-\delta, b+\delta)\not\subseteq(b-\delta, b+\delta)-\{b\}$.

Comment: @NicholasCousar Yes, when $f$ is continuous at $b$, then, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that$$|x-b|<\delta\implies\bigl|f(x)-f(b)\bigr|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Thanks! That has been bugging me for days. All the proofs of this theorem that I've seen mix the general limit definition with the limit definition for a continuous function.