# Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sin(\frac{\pi}{n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right).$

Solution:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)=\sin\left (\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{n}\right )=\sin 0= 0.$$

I just don't understand what justifies to take the $\sin$ out of the limit, would it be the property of the product between a constant and a function?

Comment: The property is *continuity*

Comment: The $\sin$ function is continuous.

Comment: Hello. We can make a replacement $t=\frac{1}{n}$ and in this case we have
$$ t=\frac{1}{n} , t\rightarrow0$$
$$ \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \sin(t \cdot \pi) = \sin(0) = 0$$

Comment: See:  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2679899/693161